# Selectpicker is not working on dropdown change

Tags: javascript

I have two dropdown one for country and another for state. i want state appears according to country. i add selectpicker class to both of the dropdown. 
but when i change the country in console it display error

**Error**

```
TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
return c.join(',');
```

**My Code**

**My Html**

```
 <select data-size="5" onchange="changeCountry(this.value)" class="form-control selectpicker bs-select-hidden" name="Tours[countryid]" id="Tours_countryid">
<option>Country1</option>
    <option>Country2</option>
    </select>

<select id="Tours_stateid" name="Tours[stateid]" data-size="5" class="form-control selectpicker bs-select-hidden" maxlength="50">
<option value="">---Select State---</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="bootstrap-select.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
 $(".selectpicker").selectpicker(); 
});


function changeCountry(value)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createurl('/site/changecountry') ?>",
                type: 'post',
                data: {id: value},
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#Tours_stateid").html(result)
                    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Show you html page. How you declared elements with "selectpicker" class.

Comment: I edit my question with my html code. have a look

Comment: You linked CSS styles for 'selectpicker'? As <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

Comment: yes i linked the selectpicker css

Answer (score 0):

Check that the library 'bootstrap-select.js' is loaded before using it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
...
    <!-- Loading library -->
    <script src="bootstrap-select.js"></script>

    <!-- Using library -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
         $(".selectpicker").selectpicker(); 
       });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <select data-size="5" onchange="changeCountry(this.value)" class="form-control selectpicker bs-select-hidden" name="Tours[countryid]" id="Tours_countryid">
      <option>Country1</option>
      <option>Country2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="Tours_stateid" name="Tours[stateid]" data-size="5" class="form-control selectpicker bs-select-hidden" maxlength="50">
      <option value="">---Select State---</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```